# Linux kernel 3.11.10 installation error

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I installed kernel 3.11.10 and now I'm getting this error message:

```
The package linux-headers-3.11.10-031110-generic needs to be reinstalled
```

But I can't find the file to do it. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Installed from where exactly? And on what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

`linux-headers-3.11.10-031110-generic` in this `3.11.10-031110` means the version number.You don't need to include it while reinstalling `linux-headers-generic`.Follow the below steps to reinstall `linux-headers-generic`,

Open a terminal by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
```

If you are forcing the installation, do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall  --force-yes linux-headers-generic
```

> **Note:-** Do **not** force update packages, unless you know what you are doing.